# How to make a CALayer with NSImage dynamically adapt to the app appearance?

Tags: objective-c, calayer, nsimage

I have an `NSView` whose `layer` has various `sublayers`.

Its `needsDisplay` property is set to `YES` when the app changes its effective appearance, which ends up calling:

```
-(void)updateLayer {
       // this is a simplified version
        sublayer1.backgroundColor = NSColor.windowBackgroundColor.CGColor;
        sublayer2.content = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dynamic image"];
       // "dynamic image" is an image asset that has light and dark variants.
}
```

Both layers render properly according to the theme after the app launches, but when the app changes theme (without being relaunched), the appearance of `sublayer2` does not change. The appearance of `sublayer1` does change, but I have to relaunch the app for `sublayer2` to update to the app theme.
Using "dynamic image" as template image or original image has no effect on this issue.

Note that the same image used in an `NSButton` does change appearance properly without having to relaunch the app.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `NSImage` will cache images based on their names.  I suspect that when you try to re-fetch the image using `imageNamed`, it is returning the cached image instead of re-searching for an image to display (and finding the one in your asset catalog).  Try doing `[(NSImage *)sublayer2.content setName: nil];` right before you set `sublayer2.content` and see if that flushes the cached image and forces the system to search for the one in the asset catalog.

Comment: I have done very little with MacOS apps, however... On iOS, we set the layer contents to a `CGImage` which will not, of course, change with appearance changes. It seems possible (likely?) that assigning a `NSImage` as a layer's content does the same (under-the-hood). Would adding a `NSImageView` as a subview be an option for your use case?

Comment: @Scott: the issue has certainly something to do with caches, but your suggestion didn't work. I also tried to call `-recache` on the image before/after removing and re-adding all images representation, together with, `NSImageCacheNever` (which should be redundant with `-recache`)... nothing works. I'd rather not use an `NSImageView`. I think I'll end up using different images for dark/light modes as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Update: The `NSImage` properly adapts to the appearance when I call `-drawInRect:` on it (within a `-drawRect:` method), without the need to recache anything. I just wouldn't change its appearance if I use it in a `CALayer`, even if I don't set it as `contents` and instead call `-drawInRect:` on the image it within `-drawLayer:InContext:`

Comment: Update: it doesn't seem to be related to caching. if I create the `CALayer` and the `NSImage` objects only *after* the app has changed appearance, the layer renders the image with the appearance that the app had on launch. It seems that `CALayer` ignores the app current appearance and relies on its initial state. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410773-contents?language=objc) for `CALayer`.`contents`:

> Discussion
>
> The default value of this property is nil.
>
> If you are using the layer to display a static image, you can set this property to the CGImageRef containing the image you want to display. (In macOS 10.6 and later, you can also set the property to an NSImage object.) Assigning a value to this property causes the layer to use your image rather than create a separate backing store.
>
> If the layer object is tied to a view object, you should avoid setting the contents of this property directly. The interplay between views and layers usually results in the view replacing the contents of this property during a subsequent update.

So, when setting:

```
sublayer2.content = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dynamic image"];
```

the layer gets a `CGImageRef`, not a `NSImage` ... and appearance changes will have no effect.

One approach would be to replace the `CALayer` with a `NSImageView` as a subview. Set the `.image` property, and you're done.

If you **need to use `CALayer`**, we need to get the `CGImageRef` from the image with the current appearance in `updateLayer`.

Quick example:

**`LayeredView.h`**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface LayeredView : NSView
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**`LayeredView.m`**

```
#import "LayeredView.h"
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>

@interface LayeredView()
{
    CALayer *imgLayer;
    NSImage *img;
}
@end

@implementation LayeredView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)commonInit {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    
    // load the image
    img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"i100x100"];
    
    // create layer
    imgLayer = [CALayer new];
    
    // .contentsGravity as desired
    imgLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
    
    // add the layer
    [self.layer addSublayer:imgLayer];
}
- (void)updateLayer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super updateLayer];
    
    // built-in layer animation will result in a "fade"
    //  so disable it (if desired)
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
    
    if (img) {
        // get the CGImageRef from img -- this will reflect light/dark mode
        imgLayer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([img CGImageForProposedRect:nil context:nil hints:nil]);
    }

    // image layer frame as desired
    imgLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    [CATransaction commit];
}
@end
```